# Estoy intentando validar la entrada a un formulario pero me marca un error

Tags: php

```
    <?php
        include '../admin/conexion.php';
        if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
            
            $usuario = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']));
            $pw = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

        //  $numero = srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

            $log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE NombreUsuario='$usuario' AND PassUsuario='$pw'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($log)>0) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($log);

                $_SESSION["NombreUsuario"] = $row['NombreUsuario']; 
                $_SESSION["NivelUsuario"] = $row['NivelUsuario']; 
                $_SESSION["Codigo"] = $row['Codigo']; 
                if ($_SESSION["NivelUsuario"] == 1) {
                    echo '<script> window.location="../admin/admin.php"; </script>';
                }
                      elseif ($_SESSION["NivelUsuario"] == 2) {
                        echo '<script> window.location="../docentes/docentes.php"; </script>';
                     }

                         else {
                            echo '<script> window.location="../estudiantes/estudiantes.php"; </script>';
                            echo $numero;
                         }
            }
            else{
                echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos. ");</script>';
                echo '<script> window.location="../login.php"; </script>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

me da este error

> host via TCP/IP
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\siad\login\validar.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\siad\login\validar.php on line 8

Comment: Qué versión de PHP? Revisaste la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)? Esa función fue deprecada

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar a msqli o PDO, aquí esta la documentación de esa función con mysqli.
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php